# What is the best way to parse a log file into a python list?

Tags: python

I have an interesting log file format and I would like to parse it into Python for analysis.

The format is `key=value` with each separated by tabs, and a newline at the end of each entry, like this:

```
date="Mon, 04 Jul 2011 05:05:45 GMT"    addr=127.0.0.1  response_time=13    method=GET  url=/   status=200  referrer=   user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30"
```

Now some of the fields may be changing, so I want the code to be flexible with what is thrown at it, as long as it is in the form of `key=value key=value`(etc.)

As of now, I have two embedded `for` loops, one to split each line into the `key=value` fields, and the other to split the `key=value` into their own separate entities.

Does this seem like the best way to go or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: You need to be careful splitting this up - for example, you should check which characters can appear as part of the url or referrer and that they can't interfere with your splitting method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two `for` loops seems fine for this problem. If I were coding it, I'd probably do something like this:

```
with open('log_file') as f:
    for line in f:
        fields = line.split('\t')
        for field in fields:
            key,_,val = field.partition('=')
            # Do something with each key and val
```

Comment: What's wrong with `[ (k,v) for k,_,v in (f.partition('=') for f in line.split('\t'))]`?  Seems to do the same thing in one line.

Answer (score 2):

There probably is a module to parse log files, but a simple homemade way to this easily is to use the [shlex](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html) module:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> line = """date="Mon, 04 Jul 2011 05:05:45 GMT" addr=127.0.0.1 response_time=13 method=GET url=/ status=200 referrer= user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30" """
# Split key=value pairs.  'value' can contain quoted whitespace.
>>> keyvals = shlex.split(line)
# Separate 'key' and 'gals' for each keyval pair.
>>> data = [x.partition('=')[::2] for x in keyvals]
>>> print data
[('date', 'Mon, 04 Jul 2011 05:05:45 GMT'), ('addr', '127.0.0.1'), ('response_time', '13'), ('method', 'GET'), ('url', '/'), ('status', '200'), ('referrer', ''), ('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30')]
>>> print dict(data)
{'status': '200', 'addr': '127.0.0.1', 'url': '/', 'referrer': '', 'user_agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30', 'date': 'Mon, 04 Jul 2011 05:05:45 GMT', 'method': 'GET', 'response_time': '13'}
```

Comment: This looks great. I did not know about the shlex module. Are there any limitations?

Comment: @sdk900: `shlex` is good because it takes care of quotes etc., so it parses `date="Mon, ...."` correctly for example, even if the fields were separated by spaces and not tabs.

Answer (score 1):

The [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module for python would work great here. 
You can set the delimiter to a tab
This example is from the docs using a space.

```
>>> import csv
>>> spamReader = csv.reader(open('eggs.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
>>> for row in spamReader:
...     print ', '.join(row)
```

Then you could, inside the loop check for the '=' character and split the string if found into key value pairs.

```
result = []    
for row in spamReader:
       if '=' in row:
          s = row.split('=')
          result.append( {s[0]:s[1]} )
```

Comment: wooot! csv is at around 10 times faster than shlex! many thanks!